# How to calculate $F'(-1)$ and $F'(0)$ when $F(x)=\int_x^1 t(t^2+1)dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

For this question do you just plug in 0 or 1? The answers I got are different from what the textbook says, which are $\sqrt2$ and $0$. Could anyone tell how to calculate this?

Comment: $F(x)=\int_0^1 -\int_0^x$. Then apply fundamental theorem of calculus, and obtain $F^\prime(x)=-x(x^2+1)$, obtaining $0$ and $2$ (not $\sqrt{2}$).

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental theorem of calculus says that the derivative of $G(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$ is $f(x).$ So, write

$$G(x)=-F(x)=\int_1^x t(t^2+1)dt.$$ Then,

$$G'(0)=-F'(0)=0(0^2+1)=0\implies F'(0)=0.$$ In a similar way

$$G'(-1)=-F'(-1)=-1((-1)^2+1)=-2\implies F'(-1)=2.$$